# Using HTML5 localStorage on a contact form, incorrect values in form elements

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am creating a really basic form, which I need to utilise HTML5 localStorage on the inputs/textarea.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="local-storage">
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name:">
    <input name="website" type="url" placeholder="Website:">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message:"></textarea>
</div>
```

And the script I have so far:

```
(function () {
        var localStorageID = document.getElementById('local-storage');
        var inputTags = ['input', 'textarea', 'select', 'button'];

        for (var i = 0; i < inputTags.length; i++) {

            var localStorageTag = localStorageID.getElementsByTagName(inputTags[i]);
            var formData = {};
            for (var z = 0; z < localStorageTag.length; z++) {
                formData[localStorageTag[z].name] = localStorageTag[z].value;
            }
            localStorage.setItem('formData', formData);
            if (localStorage.getItem('formData')) {

            }

            for (var z = 0; z < localStorageTag.length; z++) {
                var currentLocalTag = localStorageTag[z];
                currentLocalTag.className += 'test';
                setInterval(function () {
                    localStorage.setItem('autosave', currentLocalTag.value);
                }, 1000);

                if (localStorage.getItem('autosave')) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < localStorageTag.length; i++) {
                        var currentLocalTags = localStorageTag[i];
                        currentLocalTags.value = localStorage.getItem('autosave');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })();
```

What I have working so far is the capturing of the data, but I think I have gone wrong somewhere as the input elements are writing the incorrect values in. I'm fairly new to JavaScript so this is a massive learning curve for me, and any help is massively appreciated.

Here's the JSFiddle of the form so far, type something in and wait a few seconds and refresh: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJZNf

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` only stores strings. If you want to store (not too heavy) objects, you have to serialize them.

You can for example use JSON :

```
// store
localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(formData));

// read
var str = localStorage.getItem('formData');
if (str) formData = JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: Thanks @dystroy, how would one going about serialising this?